# Any algorithm to find the double trouble number?

Tags: algorithm, numbers, puzzle

I was trying to code the double trouble number problem, but before that not able to finalize the algorithm. 
Anybody has any idea?

> Problem Statement -
>
> The numbers has the following property -
>
> Whenever you would right-rotate the number (that is, take away the
>   last digit and put it in front of the number), you would end up with
>   double the original number. Numbers possessing this property were
>   called double-trouble numbers. For example, X = 421052631578947368 is
>   a double-trouble number, since 2X = 842105263157894736 which is a
>   right rotation of X.
>
> The number X is a double-trouble number in the number system with base
>   10. Any number system with base  p >= 2 , however, has many such double-trouble numbers. In the binary number system (base p = 2), for
>   example, we have the double-trouble numbers 01 and 0101. Notice that
>   the leading zeros are necessary here in order to obtain the proper
>   number after right rotation.
>
> In the binary number system the smallest double-trouble number is 01. In > the decimal (p = 10) number system, the smallest double-trouble number 
>   is 052631578947368421.  I need to write a program that computes for a 
>   given base p of a number system the smallest double-trouble number in 
>   that system.

Comment: "not able to finalize the algorithm" then show us those parts that you've got.

Comment: This is explained in detail here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitic_number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the brute force solution in JavaScript.
It starts with a digit, then prepends the double of the previous digit (plus carry).
After each iteraion it tests if the digits are a double trouble number (it also tries the prepend by "0" corner/ambiguous case)

This implementation is only for base 10; you'll have to understand the algorithm and modify the code to create an arbitrary base abstraction.

**Double Trouble Solver for base 10**

```
// (digits * 2) == digits[n]:digits[1..n-1]
function isDT(digits) {
    var times2 = "";
    var carry = false;
    for(var i = digits.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var d = parseInt(digits.charAt(i));
        var d2 = "" + (d * 2 + (carry ? 1 : 0));
        carry = d2.length > 1;
        times2 = d2.charAt(d2.length > 1 ? 1 : 0) + times2;
    }
    if(carry) { times2 = "1" + times2; }
    return times2 == (digits.charAt(digits.length -1) + digits.substring(0, digits.length -1));
}
// generate a doule trouble number from a starting digit
function makeDT(digits, carry) {
    var carry = carry || false;
    var digits = "" + digits;
    if(carry && isDT("1" + digits)) {
        return "1" + digits;
    } else if(isDT(digits)) {
        return digits;
    } else if(isDT("0" + digits)) {
        return "0" + digits;
    }
    var d = digits.charAt(0);
    var d2 = "" + (d * 2 + (carry ? 1 : 0));
    carry = d2.length > 1;
    digits = d2.charAt(d2.length > 1 ? 1 : 0) + digits;
    return makeDT(digits, carry);
}
//
alert(makeDT("9"));
alert(makeDT("8"));
alert(makeDT("7"));
alert(makeDT("6"));
alert(makeDT("5"));
alert(makeDT("4"));
alert(makeDT("3"));
alert(makeDT("2"));
alert(makeDT("1"));
```

**EDIT** Here's the jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/avbfae0w/

Comment: Thanks Louis for detailed explanation.